# Android background task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to start background task. Task call async http request and if condition is valid show alert.

I implemented it but I receive this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

This is my java code:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RequestScheduledTask(), intervalTask);

    class RequestScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            myCall();
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Luca

Comment: did an update on my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to the following post you are doing something in a thread that is meant to be called on the main thread! What is `myCall();` doing?

- [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

And don't do http request with async tasks thats bad practice.

I would recomment to use volley:

- http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

[edit]

Okay its the loading indicator that is should be called on the **main thread**. I guess you are doing it in the AsyncTask.
You can use [Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable())](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to run a runnable to display it.

Answer (score 0):

for example I need refresh adapter list when data is changed. Data returned from webserver could to be changed or not. if it is changed I must refresh listview/adapter, else nothing.

myCall call server, get data response (using other framwork like volley) and then update list view.

When myCall start I want display loading indicator but when I show it, app crash with runtime exception

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```